# How do i get the headings to fit in to their cells

Tags: python, excel, csv

```
with open ('Reddit_Data.csv', 'w', newline='',encoding="utf-8-sig") as f:
    fieldnames = ['Submission_ID','Submission_Title','Submission_Comments','Submission_Sentiment']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
```

When the headings are written the size of the cells stay the same so you cant see all of the heading name. Is there a way I can get the heading to fit or perhaps change the size of the cells from python. Im using excel to look at the CSV file.

Comment: Can you use pandas? `pd.read_csv('Reddit_Data.csv',encoding="utf-8-sig")`

Comment: I guess the issue is not with the code as the csv can't contain any format or style information, but Excel just sets a particular size, when opening the csv. Open the csv with a text editor, you'll see there is no info on format, but just the whole titles.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is that CSV format does not contain any format information, only raw data separated into columns and rows. So Excel decides itself how to display your data and nothing in CSV file can change it.

If you need sheet with formatting as result, you can either save your CSV file as XLSX file manually in Excel. Or your code should export your data in other format (eg. xlsx).

For the latter you can try **openpyxl** library.

- https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
- https://realpython.com/openpyxl-excel-spreadsheets-python/